# Looking for a workaround, as radiobutton.click() hangs Safari but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have a table with some checkboxes in it, and I've added this code so that when you click on any part of specific table cells, the checkbox is checked. When a checkbox is checked, I need to remove a `disabled` class from a button in order to allow the user to move to the next step.

This code works fine in Chrome, but in Safari it hangs the window, immediately when `$('input:radio', $parent).click()` is called.

Is there a more correct way to be doing this?

```
$('td.info, td.control').click(function() {
  var $parent;
  $parent = $(this).parent();
  $('input:radio', $parent).attr('checked', true);
  return $('input:radio', $parent).click();
});
$("input[name='package[order_option_id]']").click(function() {
  return ($("#select-interaction-link")).removeClass('disabled');
});
```

Comment: (offtopic) why not `var $parent = $(this).parent();`

Comment: And $('input:radio', $parent).prop('checked', true); is better

Comment: why do you RETURN `return $('input:radio', $parent).click();` and not just trigger the event: `$('input:radio', $parent).click();` or `$('input:radio', $parent).trigger('click');`, what is the intent of that?

Comment: the depricated attr for properties will not work (removed) in 1.9 version

Comment: This is generated from CoffeeScript. It does some things that the average bear would not. As for "why not", partially because I'm debugging and partially because CS generates code.

Comment: Yes, and my thought went to `$(this).parent().find('input:radio').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');` to chain it up, but understand the "debugging" mode might differ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the reason for the hang is that you're causing an infinite loop. When the code clicks on the radio button, the click bubbles up to the containing `td`, which causes your `click()` handler to be run again.

I think you can solve this with:

```
$("td.info input:radio, td.control input.radio").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without using a context :

```
$('td.info, td.control').click(function() {
    return $(this).parent().find('input[type=radio]').attr('checked', true).click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't fix the problem. It's more or less what I had before I started pulling the pieces apart to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is affecting Safari but if you want to check a radio, change this

```
$('input:radio', $parent).attr('checked', true);
```

to this

```
$('input:radio', $parent).prop('checked', true); // Uses the js property value
```

or

```
$('input:radio', $parent).attr('checked', 'checked'); // Uses the attribute
```

Also remember that events bubble up... not sure if you could create some kind of loop by explicitly calling the click function on the radio here but I would step through it with Safari and make sure that's not happening.  Just paranoia.